# Why does single electron Coulomb blockade charging use $Q^2/2C$?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, quantum-tunneling

Classically stored energy of a capacitor is $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$.
However, the difference in energy when a single electron travels across the gates should be $qV$
But in couloumb blockade calculations, people use $\frac{(Q+q)^2}{2C}-\frac{Q^2}{2C}$ as the difference when a single electron tunnels. Why so?